# Create list of unique elements of array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 1-dimensional array like so (where the values are repeeated.)

```
Administration   Oral ,Aged ,Area Under Curve ,Cholinergic Antagonists/adverse effects/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use ,Circadian Rhythm/physiology ,Cross-Over Studies ,Delayed-Action Preparations ,Dose-Response Relationship   Drug ,Drug Administration Schedule ,Female ,Humans ,Mandelic Acids/adverse effects/blood/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use ,Metabolic Clearance Rate ,Middle Aged ,Urinary Incontinence/drug therapy ,Xerostomia/chemically induced ,

Adult ,Anti-Ulcer Agents/metabolism ,Antihypertensive Agents/metabolism ,Benzhydryl Compounds/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology ,Caffeine/*metabolism ,Central Nervous System Stimulants/metabolism ,Cresols/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology ,Cross-Over Studies ,Cytochromes/*pharmacology ,Debrisoquin/*metabolism ,Drug Interactions ,Humans ,Male ,Muscarinic Antagonists/pharmacology ,Omeprazole/*metabolism ,*Phenylpropanolamine ,Polymorphism   Genetic ,Tolterodine Tartrate ,Urinary Bladder Diseases/drug therapy ,
...
...
```

I need a list of all the unique categories, where categories are separated by commas. eg. Administration   Oral would be one category.

Comment: Show us what have you done (code) so far and where were your difficulties/errors.

Comment: Python uses lists, not arrays as the main datatype.

Comment: Not sure but I thought numarray module allowed for arrays, including multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: @glant you are thinking of `numpy` but this question doesn't seem to be `numpy` related. Regardless.

Comment: ahh I see..Got it

Answer (score 2):

> I need a list of all the unique categories

Take any list and apply `set()` on it. Note: this removes ordering.

> where categories are separated by commas

So `split(",")` the string

For example.

```
s = '''Administration   Oral ,Aged ,Area Under Curve ,Cholinergic Antagonists/adverse effects/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use ,Circadian Rhythm/physiology ,Cross-Over Studies ,Delayed-Action Preparations ,Dose-Response Relationship   Drug'''.strip()

for x in sorted(set(s.split(","))):
  print(x.strip())
```

Outputs

```
Administration   Oral
Aged
Area Under Curve
Cholinergic Antagonists/adverse effects/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use
Circadian Rhythm/physiology
Cross-Over Studies
Delayed-Action Preparations
Dose-Response Relationship   Drug
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
categories = """Administration   Oral ,Aged ,Area Under Curve ,Cholinergic Antagonists/adverse effects/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use ,Circadian Rhythm/physiology ,Cross-Over Studies ,Delayed-Action Preparations ,Dose-Response Relationship   Drug ,Drug Administration Schedule ,Female ,Humans ,Mandelic Acids/adverse effects/blood/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use ,Metabolic Clearance Rate ,Middle Aged ,Urinary Incontinence/drug therapy ,Xerostomia/chemically induced ,Adult ,Anti-Ulcer Agents/metabolism ,Antihypertensive Agents/metabolism ,Benzhydryl Compounds/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology ,Caffeine/*metabolism ,Central Nervous System Stimulants/metabolism ,Cresols/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology ,Cross-Over Studies ,Cytochromes/*pharmacology ,Debrisoquin/*metabolism ,Drug Interactions ,Humans ,Male ,Muscarinic Antagonists/pharmacology ,Omeprazole/*metabolism ,*Phenylpropanolamine ,Polymorphism   Genetic ,Tolterodine Tartrate ,Urinary Bladder Diseases/drug therapy ,"""

category_list = [x.strip() for x in categories.split(',')]
unique_categories = filter(None, list(set(category_list)))
>>> unique_categories
['Urinary Incontinence/drug therapy', 'Debrisoquin/*metabolism', 'Cresols/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology', 'Cholinergic Antagonists/adverse effects/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use', 'Urinary Bladder Diseases/drug therapy', '*Phenylpropanolamine', 'Drug Administration Schedule', 'Tolterodine Tartrate', 'Middle Aged', 'Dose-Response Relationship   Drug', 'Polymorphism   Genetic', 'Adult', 'Anti-Ulcer Agents/metabolism', 'Caffeine/*metabolism', 'Mandelic Acids/adverse effects/blood/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use', 'Area Under Curve', 'Metabolic Clearance Rate', 'Muscarinic Antagonists/pharmacology', 'Drug Interactions', 'Delayed-Action Preparations', 'Circadian Rhythm/physiology', 'Male', 'Xerostomia/chemically induced', 'Administration   Oral', 'Cross-Over Studies', 'Benzhydryl Compounds/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology', 'Cytochromes/*pharmacology', 'Humans', 'Central Nervous System Stimulants/metabolism', 'Omeprazole/*metabolism', 'Female', 'Antihypertensive Agents/metabolism', 'Aged']
```